# IMultiValueConverter what causes Convert() to be called?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have been experimenting with the `IMultiValueConverter` interface in my WPF project, and I have noticed that the `Convert` method is called at places I would not expect it to be. For example:

I have a DataGrid in my project, and in it I have an editable `DataGridTemplateColumn`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=textBox1}">
                            <TextBox Name="textBox1"  GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus"  Margin="0" Padding="-2" MaxHeight="29"  Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MvcForeground}">
                                                <Binding Path="Value" />
                                                <Binding Path="OriginalValue" Mode="OneTime"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I have a class that implements the `IMultiValueConverter` interface:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace StupidTest
{
    public class MvcForeground : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var changed = Brushes.Red;
            var unchanged = Brushes.Black;

            if (values.Count() == 2)
            {
                if (values[0].Equals(values[1]))

                    return unchanged;
                else
                    return changed;
            }
            else
                return unchanged;
        }

        public object Reset()
        {
            return Brushes.Black;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, System.Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

}
```

You might be able to tell already, but this is my system for "Dirty Flags" in my datagrid. When I change a value in that column, the text changes to red, as it is not saved. When I press the save button, however, the values update, but the color does not update. In the course of troubleshooting this, I put some breakpoints on the `Convert` method, and I am very confused by what I saw.

The method was called whenever a TextBox lost focus, and properly updated the color of the text. It also seems to call whenever my DataGrid is populated, and is called once for each item.

I couldn't figure out how to set the color back to black upon pressing the save button, so I tried changing the `DataGridTemplateColumn` to a `DataGridTextColumn` to make that possible. However, when I did that, the `Convert` method called at entirely different times. Now, it calls as soon as the application is launched, and before my DataGrid has an item source, and is never called again, even if I change the values in the column.

As a novice in WPF, I am completely baffled by this. I assume that `Convert` is called implicitly, somehow, but I have no idea what triggers it.

***TL;DR***

The `Convert` method of my class seems to be called at the strangest of times, and I think I need to manually call it in order to reset the dirty flags when I press a button. **So what exactly causes the method to be called, and how can I call it manually in my code?**

Also, if I am going about solving this problem entirely wrong, please let me know. I have exhausted every resource I can find trying to solve this problem. I appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: is there a reason for `OneTime` mode on `OriginalValue` ?

Comment: I was following an old tutorial for MultiValueConverters and it suggested that. I suppose I never gave it a second thought

Comment: You know, there are times when i feel like an absolute idiot.

Comment: This is one of those times

Comment: LOL! glad to help :) I marked this question as off-topic since it was a typo mistake.

Comment: Now, call me a novice if you will, but why was that causing a problem?

Comment: OneTime (like it name) updates the source of the binding only one time and never again. you can search about `Binding Mode` for a better insight.

Comment: Or more precisely, it updates the *target* property once.

Comment: I thought as much. Why then did it properly update if I focused and unfocused the text box?